# Android prevent scrolling or touch the recyclerview and just with click on another button scroll the recycler

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, ontouchlistener

I have a recyclerview and I put a view on it to disable all touch event on my
recyclerview but when in another button click I call the smoothScrollToPosition event of recycelrView then all touch and scroll become active which I don't want

Can anybody help me?
Thanks

Comment: Please add some code to your question.

Comment: @krishan

I put my code below 
u can read it 

I disable the touch event of top view of recyclerview but while I call "recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);" the touch of upper view become active again and i can scroll the recyclerview

thanks